# IBOutlet connected but not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iboutlet

I had a class(dicecontroller) with an IBAction and that would trigger some IBOutlets, all was happy. I since found a better way to organize my code and put the IBAction in a different class(playercommand). playercomman calls a method in dicecontroller which has all the IBOutlets, except now none of the outlets display anything. I reconnected the outlets with the xib, even made new outlets, no form of IBOutlets seem to work. However NSLog works just fine and the array i'm passing it is being received fine.

I've had trouble with Xcode acting weird and crashing recently which was fixed by reinstalling Xcode, i did that again thinking this might be another glitch, but no love. I'm thinking this is some nuance of IB that i just don't know about

I also don't really know how to look this up, been trying to find something for hours. Help would be encouraging.

PlayerCommand.h

```
#import "DiceRoll.h"
#import "diceController.h"

@interface playerCommand : NSObject

- (IBAction)roll:(NSButton *)sender;

@end
```

Playercommand.m

```
#import "playerCommand.h"

@implementation playerCommand

- (IBAction)roll:(NSButton *)sender {

    DiceRoll *currentTurn = [[DiceRoll alloc] init];
    [currentTurn rolldice];

    diceController *currentFields = [[diceController alloc] init];
    [currentFields updatetockNameField:[currentTurn diceValuesArray]];

}
@end
```

dicecontroller.h

```
@interface diceController : NSObject

-(void)updatetockNameField: (NSArray*) diceValues;

@end
```

dicecontroller.m

```
#import "diceController.h"

// declaring private properties

@interface diceController()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *ActionField;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *QuantityField;

@end

@implementation diceController

-(void)updatetockNameField:(NSArray *) diceValues {

    switch ([[diceValues objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]) {
      case 0 ... 1:
        [[self ActionField] setStringValue:@"Up"];
        break;
      case 2 ... 3:
        [[self ActionField] setStringValue:@"Down"];
        break;
      case 4 ... 5:
        [[self ActionField] setStringValue:@"Div"];
        break;
      default:
        [[self ActionField] setStringValue:@"Err"];
        break;
    }

    switch ([[diceValues objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]) {
      case 0 ... 1:
        [[self QuantityField] setIntegerValue:5];
        break;
      case 2 ... 3:
        [[self QuantityField] setIntegerValue:10];
        break;
      case 4 ... 5:
        [[self QuantityField] setIntegerValue:20];
        break;
      default:
        [[self QuantityField] setStringValue:@"E"];
        break;
    }

} //end of updatetockNameField method


@end
```

Comment: Pls post some code, particularly an example of the calls in "that class calls the one with the IBOutlets". Also please give names to "that" class and "this" class, etc., so people can refer to these names in their answers to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

> `diceController *currentFields = [[diceController alloc] init];`

This `diceController` instance is a new instance (you create it in this line). This is not the same `diceController` instance which you had already placed and configured in your nib.

If your `playerCommand` instance needs a reference to your `diceController` instance in the nib, then you can make an IBOutlet in `playerCommand` and connect that to the `diceController` instance in your nib.

BTW, `playerCommand` and `diceController` should be named `PlayerCommand` and `DiceController`, respectively.

Comment: Are you saying the nib creates an instance of the dice controller? So there are two instances of dice controller, and my coded one doesn't relate to the nib? Thank you BTW for your help!

Comment: When the nib is loaded, an instance is created. And that's right, that instance is different from the one you created in code. They are of the same class, but they are two different instances of that class.

Comment: Is it general invention to keep IBActions and IBOutlets in the same instance so to avoid situations like these?

Comment: I don't think I would say that as a general convention, but I do think the way you've done this here seems a bit strange to me. It's hard to say with certainty without knowing more about what you are building. For now, I hope you see this is no glitch in IB or Xcode, this is just different instances of a class.

Comment: Totally, i understand what's going on here. I'll restructure it for sure. Thank you for your time and you patience!